# AngularJs code organizing nuget package

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nuget-package

I am trying to start a new angularjs application with visual studio. I heard that there is specific folder structure to organize angular code. Is there any nuget package which does the folder structure and add crequired basic js files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the app you are making you can choose for a different approach on how to build your folder structure. There are as far as I know no nuget packages that create that specific structure, but off course there are all the AngularJS nuget packages that add every .js file you need to run an Angular application. Just search for [AngularJS](https://www.nuget.org/packages/angularjs/) in your Nuget Package Manager.

You could also read an [article on best practices](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure) for the folder structure in AngularJS.